# Calling dialogue script from NPC using Interactable script (Brackeys' system)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I have followed a tutorial on Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nRzoTzeyxU) on how to create a dialogue system for a game. Since my game is a platformer/RPG, I am currently attempting to adapt this system to where the player can walk up to an NPC and press the "Submit" button to access their dialogue, instead of clicking a button on the canvas/UI.

So far I have created an Interactable script that allows the player to detect if they are in the range of the invisible sphere collider that is equipped to the NPC, which is working. If I try to access the dialogueTrigger script that is equipped to the NPC however, I get a NullReferenceException error. I would like some help on how to properly call the dialogueTrigger script from the NPC and trigger the dialogue event, as I am very new to code and I only have this so far. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>       Interactable.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Interactable.cs:34)

Dialogue Trigger is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour 

{
    public Dialogue dialogue;

    public void TriggerDialogue ()
    {
        FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue);
    }
}
```

Interactable is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Interactable : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private GameObject triggeringNpc;
    private bool triggering;
    public DialogueTrigger Diag;

    void Start()
    {

    }   

    void Update() 
    {
        if(triggering)
        {
            Debug.Log("Within Range");
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Submit"))
            {
                Debug.Log("Pressed the Interact Button");
                Diag.TriggerDialogue();
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "NPC")
        {
            triggering = true;
            triggeringNpc = other.gameObject;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "NPC")
        {
            triggering = false;
            triggeringNpc = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Posting your `DialogueTrigger` code and the full error message would be really helpful. :)

Comment: Just now edited it. Thanks!

Comment: I replaced that line and got 

    `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of  
    an object
    Interactable.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Interactable.cs:34)`

Comment: In that case, the culprit would be your `Diag` reference. Have you correctly dragged a `DialogueTrigger` prefab from your Hierarchy window and into the public field on `Interactable`?

Comment: At first, no. Then I tried and it works now, but not quite how I pictured that it would. Although that is on my end to fix, and you've still helped me get it to work in the first place. So thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear it's working :)

Comment: It is working but it is only calling the script that I put into the public 'slot' in unity, which in reality I need to be able to call the script that's attached to each different NPCs during the game. Would you know how to do that? I've tried GetComponent but either that doesn't work or I'm not doing it correctly.

Comment: Thank you Lece. It will take me some time as I am busy at the moment but I'll be sure to post once I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit would be your `Diag` reference. Have you correctly dragged a `DialogueTrigger` prefab from your Hierarchy window and into the public field on `Interactable`?